# How to Request publish permission after logged in Unity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-permissions

I know there is a function in iOS/Android SDK known as `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions`.

But I couldn't find this function in Unity FB SDK. How can I achieve this?

I know permissions can be stated during Login. What if the user doesn't allow publish permissions and later on the user click on Share/Post to wall. At least I have to prompt the user and ask for permissions again.

Anyone has any workaround to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call the [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Login)  with the `publish_action`/`public_stream` permission wherever you want to ask for the publishing permission-

```
FB.Login("publish_action", AuthCallback);
```

To find out which permissions user have at any given time, you can read the `/user/permissions` Graph API endpoint, by writing something like-

```
FB.API("/me/permissions", HttpMethod.GET, delegate (FBResult response) {
  // inspect the response and adapt your UI as appropriate
  // check response.Text and response.Error
});
```

Comment: as of today it is not allowed to call the permission "publish_actions" with the login request.